# Is it possible to use Visual Basic Express 2008 and develop apps to run on the .net framework 1.0?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, .net-1.0

I'm trying to develop an app with Microsoft's Visual Basic Express 2008 to run on the .net framework 1.0. Is there something I can download to do this or do I have to require the latest framework to be downloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No:

- You can only develop against .NET 1.0 by using Visual Studio .NET 2002.
- You can develop against .NET 1.1 using Visual Studio .NET 2003.
- You can develop against .NET 2.0 and 3.0 (IIRC) using Visual Studio 2005.
- You can develop against .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 using Visual Studio 2008.
- You can develop against .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 using Visual Studio 2010.

You could still *compile* against .NET 1.0 or .NET 1.1 if you've got those installed by running the command line tools directly - but you won't be able to use Visual Studio to build without a fair chunk of work, IIRC. (I seem to remember there *is* a tool to allow it, but I don't know how well it works, and I doubt that it's supported now.)